# Ip phone problem cannot get an ip address from dhcp using other vlans except from vlan 1

Tags: cisco, vlan, dhcp, voice, cisco-7900-ip-phones

i am trying to understand native vlans. when i use vlan 1 it worked and it provides an ip address to my ip phone. When using vlan 100 it does not work even i tried using native trunking on it. please if everybody knows if have a misconfig or if there is a bug on PT let me know i am new and working on my skills thank you so much

**PACKET TRACER 7.2.1:**

**if use vlan 1 :**
[image]
[image]

IT WORKED fine using VLAN 1

[image]

current configuration :

but using this configs:

**ROUTER**

[image]
[image]

**SWITCH**

[image]
[image]

it does not work :(

thanks in advance for replies and feedback.. YOUR HELP IS GREATLY APPRECIATED..

merry Christmas.

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Simply copy the text and paste it into the question using the Preformatted-text feature (`{}`).

Comment: I will change that next time thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether tagged or untagged/native - your VLAN requires connectivity.

Make sure there's a DHCP server attached to the VLAN *or* there's a DHCP relay set up (SVI on the switch and relay-capable DHCP server with scope set up). Also, if the VLAN requires connectivity to elsewhere there needs to be a gateway/router set up.

If you use VLAN tagging, make sure that *both sides of the link are set up in the exact same way*.

As it is, the switch's Fa0/1 is in trunk mode (=tagged frames) but the router's Fa0/0 isn't (=untagged frames). The switch accepts untagged frames from the router as belonging to VLAN 100 but it still tags frames towards the router (which are dropped there).

If you want to trunk to the router it requires the VLANs to be set up on the router as well. Alternatively, don't use a trunk but an access interface towards the router.

Comment: i put a encapsulation dot1q 1 or 100 as native and still does not work, i followed every tutorial on youtube and still does not work only the vlan 1 works. i tried getting a referrence from this site https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/inter-vlan-routing/14976-50.html   and still does not work i am not sure if this is a bug on PT. if you have any configurations on this pls help me out thanks a lot sir Zac67.

Comment: Native = untagged.

Comment: Thanks Zac like access to access trunk to trunk

Answer (score 0):

check "**show vlan**" in switch.
check with a PC in vlan 100 that **vlan 100 can communicate with DHCP Server/Call manager**.
Create an "**interface vlan**" ip in switch and check communication between switch and router
reset phone to find if the phone is stuck with configuration of vlan-1
As i knew, your scenario should work with vlan 100.

Comment: i've tried that and i can only ping vlan 1 since im using layer 2 i have not activated any ip routing on SW. i tried using pc's to connect over to the switch and they got ping reply from vlan 1 and vlan 100. but still ip phone cannot acquire any ip from the dhcp serv but data pc's can.

Comment: ip routing correction: * Switch(config)#ip routing

Answer (score 0):

Then it is only telephone issue, not a network issue as i think, specify vlan tag "100" manually in the phone and try DHCP and static IP in the phone.

Comment: I tried int fa0/1 switchport mode trunk and switchport access vlan 100 it worked

Comment: so can you give the summary, if you understood the problem of your configuration.